# Testing the parameters of a method in a factory

Tags: angularjs

Good morning,

I am trying to test the values of some fields of a method defined in a AngularJS's factory.

My code is the following :

```js
'use strict';

services.factory('toto', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return  $resource('abc',
        {},
        {
            method1: {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'urlXYZ'
            }
        })
}]);
```

I would like to check the value of method and url in method1.

I tried many things but none is ok :

```js
beforeEach(function(){
    module('myApp');
});

describe('tests', function () {
    var toto;

    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function (_toto_) {
            toto = _toto_;
        });
    });

    // check to see if it has the expected function
    describe('toto service has the expected properties', function() {

        it('should have a method1 function', function () {
            expect(angular.isFunction(toto.method1)).toBe(true);
        });

        it('should have a method1 function with the field method defined', function () {
            expect(toto.method1.url).toBeDefined();
        });

    });

});
```

It only says me that " Expected undefined to be defined." for the second test.

Do you have any idea of how I could manage to do whant I want ?

EDIT : I am not sure I was very understandable ...
What I want to do is checking the values of the url and method parameters of method1 in order to know if someone does not modify them by mistake.

EDIT 2 : Here is a solution with the help of qwetty.

```js
it('should perform POST request to the expected url', function () {
            $httpBackend
                .expectPOST('the expected url')
                .respond({});
            toto.paginate();
            $httpBackend.flush();

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In test I would call "additional" method defined in Your $resource factory.

```
it('should perform POST request and method should be available', function () {
    $httpBackend
            .expectPOST('some expected url')
            .respond({}); // does not matter what You return here ...
    toto.method1();

});
```

Comment: Your solution runs but not the way I want... I want to check the value of the parameters url and method. In your solution, I can set what I want as 'some expected url' or even use the 'expectGET' method instead of 'expectPOST', the test is OK.

Comment: The test I wrote check value of parameter `url` in method `method1`.

Comment: CD..
If You change (in future) value of parameter url the test will fail. The same applies to the method name. Different name will not perform request and `expectPOST` will not be matched and it raise an error. So both url and method are fully tested in single/small/readable test.

Comment: I have now a functionnal solution, thanks for your help. You just need to add '$httpBackend.flush()' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the resource object method `toto.method1` is a function, not an object as you defined in `$resource()`.

I think you can change the return of factory

```
services.factory('toto', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var action = {
         method1: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'urlXYZ'
        }
    };
    return  {
         resource: $resource('abc',{}, action),
         action: action
     };
}]);
```

Of course, you will also need to change the way you use the factory.

Or use `defineProperty`:

```
services.factory('toto', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var action = {
         method1: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'urlXYZ'
        }
    };
    var resource = $resource('abc',{}, action);
    Object.defineProperty(resource, 'method1', {
        value: action.method1
    });
    return resource;
}]);
```

Although it seems too much effort just for testing purpose. :)